# "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-cluster

I have set up a private cluster on GKE with k8s version `1.18.12-gke.1206` and Access to cluster endpoint is set to **Public endpoint access enabled, authorized networks disabled.** I'm running an ingress controller on this cluster of type https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx. Which uses a configMap to store configuration. But somehow any request coming to this controller, is giving an Unauthorized error with logs as:

```
2021-02-23 11:24:59.435 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:45.072 IST     "error retrieving resource lock sb-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:40.727 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:40.132 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:37.318 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:37.038 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:29.891 IST     "error retrieving resource lock sb-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:26.263 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:18.259 IST     "error retrieving resource lock sb-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:09.907 IST     "error retrieving resource lock sb-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:06.612 IST     "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Unauthorized"
2021-02-23 11:24:02.078 IST     "error retrieving resource lock sb-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx: Unauthorized"
```

we tried to follow the steps mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/). and we are getting

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   233  100   233    0     0  17282      0 {-:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}--:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17923
```

at the last Step which is: `kubectl exec test -- curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN_VALUE" https://10.0.0.1`

I'm new to GCP and K8s, can't figure out what wrong I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check whether automountServiceAccountToken had been set to false on your ServiceAccount? If so, set it to true might help.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-service-account
automountServiceAccountToken: false # set to true
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server

Comment: If my answer works for you, please thumb it up so it can help others. Thanks!